# Mysql query to get records from a range of records

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in my database,Now I want to fetch all records which start from one product value to the next product value.I mean all records starting from one 'product' to the next product value. 
Updated:

The Item_Type will always have two values either product or rule.So we have to find all the records starting from product value to the last rule value.

```
id   Item_Type       Product_ID 
1    product          512350       
2    rule             541   
3    rule             5431
4    rule             5421  
5    rule             5431  
6    rule             5241
7    product          5350  
8    rule             5541   
9    rule             5341
10    rule             5421  
11    rule             5141  
12    rule             54411   
13    product          51250   
14    rule             541   
15    rule             541
16    rule             541  
17    rule             541  
18    rule             541 
19    product          512350   
20    rule             541   
21    rule             541
```

Please help me how it can done in mysql query.

Comment: Is there any order in this list of records? How do we know which records are "between" two particular products?

Comment: Please show desired output. To Aioros comment, is there an auto-increment column that you're not showing that provides the order? InnoDB?

Comment: we have to find the all records between product and the last rule before the next product.

Comment: we are seriously thinking about output instead of him...

Comment: actually this is a very large table containing more than 100 fields. I have created this table from a csv file through script.And all the records are inserted from reading that csv file

Comment: More than 100 fields is not a very large table. More than 100 million rows - yes this is good table.

Comment: To reiterate, there is no 'row order' in MySQL, so you have to have some way of establishing which row succeeds which. A popular method is to construct an auto_incrementing id - but this should be in place BEFORE you start inserting data into your table!

Comment: The value of the Item_Type will be either product or rule,so we have to find all records starting from product to the last rule value.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that there is no implicit order in the table rows. You posted them in an order that you arbitrarily decided, so there is no way for the engine (and for any of us) to know which rules belong to which product. You should definitely use two tables in your import: one for products, one for rules having a product foreign key.

Comment: So if I put an auto increment id in the table, then will the solution be possible ?

Comment: Yes, even if a two-table approach would be extremely easier to understand and use.

Comment: I have updated my question. Now I have put a primary key in the table which is auto incrment.Can you guy help me now ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to start from product 5350, you could do something horrible like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM thetable
WHERE id > (SELECT id
            FROM thetable
            WHERE Product_ID = 5350)
AND id < (SELECT MIN(id)
          FROM thetable
          WHERE Item_Type = product
          AND id > (SELECT id FROM thetable WHERE Product_ID = 5350))
```

There might be a simpler query, but for such a specific situation I don't think efficiency is a must. I have to say again, though, that a two-table approach would have been much cleaner and would have made much more sense, sparing the need for such a bad querying style.

Answer (score -1):

This is the basic SQL select query :

```
SELECT *
FROM $tableName
ORDER BY $orderColumn
LIMIT $firstRowNo, $rowsCount
```

Where

- $tableName is the name of Table in your db
- $orderColumn is the column name that you want to use for sroting (probably Product_ID)
- $firstRowNo number
- $rowsCount how many rows do you want get.

Examples: Query that will load first 3 products:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Product_ID
LIMIT 0, 3;
```

Examples: Query that will load first 5,6,7,8,9 and 10th product:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Product_ID
LIMIT 5, 5;
```

When you're using limit always sort row by selected column, it will help you determine how fields are sorted and the order will be always the same, even if you change the DB engine.